# Jquery on/off Settimeout

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I want to do it with jQuery by clicking on the img element and making it passive. After 2 seconds, activate it again. I tried very hard but I could not. Can you help me?
My Function

```
$.deneme = function () {
            setTimeout(function myfunction() {
                alert("asdas");
                $("#menubar").on("click", this.click);
            }, 2000);
        };
```

İmg Code

```
$("#menubar").click(function myfunction() {
   $("#menubar").off("click", this.click);
                $.deneme()
            }
```

Comment: What's `this.click`?

Comment: it may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#menubar').on('click', function onClick() {
    console.log('clicked');
    $('#menubar').off('click', onClick);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#menubar').on('click', onClick);
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="menubar" src="#" alt="some image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to, lets say pause an element Event, the event declaration and the actual code of the event should be separated, your logic its fine in this way, but code needs some work

```js
var cont = 0;
var clickable = function(){
    pausethis(2); // pause event click for 2 seconds
    // actual executable code for the Even
    console.log(cont++)
}

var pausethis = function(seconds){
   $('.elementbyid').off('click');// remove click event
    setTimeout(function(){ // timer for 2 seconds
      $('.elementbyid').off().on('click',clickable);// add event again
    },(seconds*1000));
}

$('.elementbyid').on('click',clickable); // jquery event calls a function
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="elementbyid">click me</button>
```